# Getting 404 Error MVC when trying to add New Object to a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have Friend view where are my Friends are listed inside a table as show in the picture below. [image]

Now I have added new feature Add Friend so when I click on the the Link I am getting:

> The resource cannot be found. HTTP 404

Here is my View where all friends are listed:

```
@using Lab3.Models
@model IEnumerable<Lab3.Models.FriendModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Friends";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Friends</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Add Friend", "AddNewFriend", "Friend", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Friend Id</th>
            <th>Friend Name</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (FriendModel friend in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@friend.Id</td>
                <td>@friend.Ime</td>
                <td>@friend.MestoZiveenje</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditFriend", new { id = friend.Id }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

The `AddFriend` view:

```
@model Lab3.Models.FriendModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddFriend";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AddFriend</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewFriend","Friend")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>FriendModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MestoZiveenje, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MestoZiveenje, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MestoZiveenje, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And my the `FriendController`:

```cs
using Lab3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lab3.Controllers
{
    public class FriendController : Controller
    {
        private static List<FriendModel> friendModels;

        // GET: Friend
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var friends = GetFriends();

            return View(friends);  
        }

        public ViewResult EditFriend(byte id)
        {
            var friend = GetFriends().SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);  
            return View("EditFriend",friend);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddNewFriend(FriendModel friend)    
        {
            friendModels.Add(friend);
            return View("Index", friendModels);
        }

        private IEnumerable<FriendModel> GetFriends()
        {
            return new List<FriendModel>
            {
                new FriendModel {Id = 1, Ime = "Marry", MestoZiveenje = "Dubai"},
                new FriendModel {Id = 2, Ime = "John", MestoZiveenje = "London"},
                new FriendModel {Id = 3, Ime = "Smith", MestoZiveenje = "Manchester"}
            };
        }       
    }
}
```

Why I am getting this ***404 Error*** Page not found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no action for your `AddNewFriend` View to redirect, a view should have a action with method `get` to redirect, and `post` methods are for once you submit the form in your view

Add below method in your controller it should solve the issue

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddNewFriend()    
{            
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error 404 means it can't find a route from your URL.

Check this line in your Razor page

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditFriend", new { id = friend.Id }, null)
```

Here you are telling, When I click the link, Goto `controller:"Edit" & action:"EditFriend"`.
This will resolve to "https://localhost/Edit/EditFriend?id=1"

But I can't find a EditController here and thus this link creates 404

---

Try putting "`Friend`" here because we have a "`FriendController`". Like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Friend", "EditFriend", new { id = friend.Id }, null)
```

This will resolve to "https://localhost/Friend/EditFriend?id=1"